# URL amigável + GET no mesmo link

Tags: php

Preciso de uma regra de rewrite (.htaccess) que possibilite o uso de URL amigável e o GET normal no mesmo link, exemplo:

```
meusite.com/teste?t=0&t2=1
```

Que seria o mesmo que:

```
meusite.com/?p=teste&t=0&t2=1
```

Comment: Não seria a *flag* [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) que você precisa?

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado.